# Making a div always on top of a canvas that always write something

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am continuously drawing some lines in my canvas using `kinetic.js` and I want a div-text to appear on top of this canvas. Using `relative` and `absolute` trick I can place a div in the middle of my canvas but the problem is as I am continuously drawing lines, these lines are being drawn on top of my div-texts which I dont want to happen!

Basic template:

```
    <div id="div-text" style="background-color:#00baba; position: absolute; margin-top: 50%; margin-left: 50%;">
        greatTexts
   </div>

   <div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
   <canvas></canvas> 
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could also just set a `z-index` value on both `#container` and `#div-text`. 
Like this:

```
<div id="div-text" style="background-color:#00baba; position: absolute; margin-top: 50%; margin-left: 50%;z-index:999;">
        greatTexts
   </div>

  <div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;z-index:990;">
     <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500" width="500"></canvas> 
   </div>
```

[This](http://jsbin.com/uxijin/1/edit) shows an example.

Answer (score 0):

A canvas if by default empty, meaning you can see elements behind it.

Since you placed your `<div>` **before** the `<canvas>`, in the code, the `<div>` is rendered **under** the `<canvas>`.

Solution? Switch the divs around a little:

```
<div>
    <canvas style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background:red"></canvas> 
    <div id="div-text" style="background-color:#00baba; position:absolute; margin-top:50%; margin-left:50%;">
        greatTexts
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually `kinetic.js` is writing that `canvas` programmatically, so I dont have much of a choice to write div up or down! :S Will it help if I add it create this div using javascript after `kinetic.js` creates `canvas`? How would I know if it has created or not! :S

Answer (score 0):

Just place the div with text after the container div like this

```
   <div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;">

   <div id="div-text" style="background-color:#00baba; position: absolute; margin-top: 50%; margin-left: 50%;">
        greatTexts
   </div>
```

There's no need to create a canvas element, because as you've mentioned, KineticJS automatically creates those for you.